# Updating and reading states with boolean values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean, state

There's something I noticed about states with boolean value in Javascript. Consider the small React experiment below
that imitates how the Like button in Facebook works on client-side:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        liked: false,
        likes: 34
    }

    toggleLike = (e) => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            liked: !state.liked,
            likes: (!state.liked) ? state.likes + 1 : state.likes - 1
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.toggleLike}>
                <label className={(this.state.liked) ? 'liked' : null}>Like:</label>
                <span>{this.state.likes}</span>
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

If the `this.state.liked` is `true`, the likes count must increment by 1 and the "Like" label must add a class name called
`liked`, which turns the text color into lightblue. There's no error in the code but this is what makes it confusing to me:

In the `toggleLike()` method, the condition is `(!state.liked)`; but in className rendering in HTML, it's `(this.state.liked)`

I don't understand if it means "if the new state value is not equal to the initial value" or "if the new state value is true or false".

Answer (score 0):

Both are checking "if the new state value is true or false".

The render displays the className according to the current state value ("if the new state is true do something, otherwise do something else").
setState, on the other hand, uses the negated value since it wants to set the likes based on the previous value ("if the new state is false do something, otherwise do something else").

setState could also use `state.liked` and not `!state.liked`, and then instead of writing:

```
likes: (!state.liked) ? state.likes + 1 : state.likes - 1
```

The code would be:

```
likes: (state.liked) ? state.likes -1 : state.likes + 1
```

Bottom line - both could use `state.liked` and be, probably, less confusing.

Comment: Thanks. It's how `setState` works that I should understand

Comment: I am glad...  :)